# Is there any relationship between the (orthonormal) eigenvectors of $X^TX$ and $XX^T$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Specifically, suppose $X$ is an $n \times p$ matrix such that $v_1, \ldots, v_p$ are orthonormal eigenvectors (w/ associated eigenvalues $\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_p$) of $X^TX$. Can any assumptions be made about the eigenvectors or eigenvalues of $XX^T$?

Comment: They're the right resp. left singular vectors of $X$: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition

Comment: @dp $XX^T$ and $X^TX$ have the same non-zero eigenvalues

Comment: Observe that if $X^TXv=\lambda v$  for $v\neq 0$ and $\lambda \neq 0$ then $XX^TXv=\lambda Xv.$and $Xv\neq 0.$